# Background image in text letters -> doesn't work on Mozilla if my screen width > 1675px

Tags: html, css

(To begin I'm french and my english is not perfect ◔_◔)

I'm working on my portfolio and I want to put an image background into they letters of my name.

Fot the moment it's work on chrome, edge but on Firefox that work when the size of the window is lower than 1675px...
I don't understand why that doesn't work and that's why I'm here.

Thanks in advance for your help !
gitlab link of my project : https://github.com/Batrap17/portfolio

```css
/* Fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
    src: url(..\fonts\archivo\ArchivoBlack-Regular.ttf);
  }

@font-face {
font-family: "nunito";
src: url(..\fonts\krona\Nunito-Regular.ttf);
}

/* General rules */

body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}

/*----- Home page -----*/

.name {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
}

.name > div {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.name__title {
    background-image: url("../img/baptiste_photo.jpg");
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    -moz-color: transparent;
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-attachment: fixed;
    -moz-background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}

.name--lastname {
    top: 25%;
}

.name__title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end; 
    height: 25vh;
}

.name__background {
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url("../img/baptiste_photo.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0%  100%;
}

/*----- Media Queries -----*/

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .name__title {
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        text-orientation: upright;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center; 
        height: 100vh;
        width: 25vw !important;
        font-size: 12vw;
        letter-spacing: -4.5vw;
    }

    .name--lastname {
        left: 25%;
        top: 0;
    }

    .name__background {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 100vh !important;
        background-position: 0% 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Baptiste Charrier</title>
    <link href=".\assets\css\reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=".\assets\css\variables.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=".\assets\css\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=".\assets\css\header.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="menu">
        <div class="menu__burger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="name">
        <h2 class="name__title">Baptiste</h2>
        <h2 class="name__title name--lastname">Charrier</h2>   
        <div class="name__background"></div>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your title question is missing a verb to be clear.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to open your GitLab link. But it says "Ce serveur gitlab est accessible aux personnes disposant d'un compte à l'université de La Rochelle." or "This gitlab server is accessible to people with an account at the University of La Rochelle."

Comment: I have upload my project on another git : https://github.com/Batrap17/portfolio

Comment: Nobody can help me ? :/